# Merge and replace table id with string of two table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have this situation:

```
Table A:
+----+------------+
| id | text       |
+----+------------+
| 33 | str1       | 
| 34 | str2       | 
| 35 | str3       | 
| 36 | str4       | 
+----+------------+

Table B:
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
| id | title  | teme | year       | ed       | cont |
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
|  8 |     33 |   34 | 2012-04-06 |       35 |    36 | 
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Is possible with one query have this result ?:

```
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
| id | title  | teme | year       | ed       | cont |
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
|  8 |   str1 | str2 | 2012-04-06 |     str3 |  str4 | 
+----+--------+------+------------+----------+-------+
```

The table A results from a JOIN between other two table.

The DBMS I used is Mysql

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can come up with is

```
select b.id, 
       (select a.text from tableA a where a.id = b.title) as title, 
       (select a.text from tableA a where a.id = b.teme) as teme, 
       year, 
       (select a.text from tableA a where a.id = b.ed) as ed, 
       (select a.text from tableA a where a.id = b.cont) as cont
from tableB b
where b.id = 8
```